# App crashes when trying to download from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am just starting with Firebase and I'm not entirely sure what causes my problem. I have done everything like the official tutorial said, but every time i try to execute function downlFile my app suddenly crashes. Can anyone tell my what is the problem?

```
{
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    var storageRef = storage.reference


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

   fun downlFile(view: View?)
   {
      var spaceRef = storageRef.child("team.png")

      val localFile = File.createTempFile("image", "png")

      spaceRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
            //Local temp file has been created
       }.addOnFailureListener {
           // Handle any errors
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: If you app crashes, find the error message and stack trace in the logcat output and add those to your question (there's an edit link right under it).

Comment: Please show us the error message and please also respond with @.